# Why am I getting a 'Failed to load template' error when trying to load my templateCache?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am starting to use `webpack` as my build tool for an `angular` project.  I am having to pull in `ng-template-loader` to create my `templateCache`.  Here is my `webpack` config:

```
{
  test: /\.html$/,
  loader: 'ngtemplate!html'
}
```

And now I can import my `html` files like this

```
var template = require('./menu.html');
```

On a couple of my `html` files, I am getting this error:

[image]

It would seem I am getting a `404`, but you can see in the error message the actual `html` `<div>Jasonn</div>`.

Any ideas on what this could mean?

Comment: Are you sure using template in the directive?

Comment: I was using templateUrl.  That was the issue.  Write up an answer and I will accept it